# How to automatically trigger dictation on button press

Tags: ios, keyboard, voice

When I tap the TextField, it shows keyboard like that:
[image]

But I want it show voice dictate like that:
[image]

Is it possible to trigger the voice command provided on ios keyboard only using code?

Comment: a) What have you tried? b) I don't think it's a good idea (and most will probably agree) to deny your users the right to type instead of dictate.

Comment: Yes I know,I just want to make question clear，In face I add a voice button,when user tapped it,then show voice dictate, when user tapped textfield,show keyboard